# Expresión regular regex en java

Tags: java, poo, regex

Tengo la clase libro la cual representa una instancia de un libro con información básica acerca de un libro como autores (lista de string con los nombres), titulo, editorial y año de publicación.

La clase tiene un método `ReadBooks(String input)` al que se la pasa una string con la información básica de un libro anteriormente detallada e inicializa los atributos globales definidos justo debajo de la cabecera de la clase.

```
public class Book {
    List<String> Authors;
    String Title;
    String Publisher;
    int PublicationYear;

    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Book> ReadBooks(String input) {
        this.Authors = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] fieldSeparator = input.split("\n");

        for(int i = 1; i < fieldSeparator.length; i++) {
            String[] separator = fieldSeparator[i].split(":");
            String key = separator[0].trim();
            String value = separator[1].trim();

            switch(key) {
                case "Author":
                    this.Authors.add(value);
                    break;

                case "Title":
                    this.Title = value;
                    break;

                case "Publisher":
                    this.Publisher = value;
                    break;

                case "Published":
                    this.PublicationYear = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    break;
            }
        }
        Book book = new Book();
        books.add(book);
        return books;
    }
```

Ahora estoy intentando añadir una función `FindBooks(String searchString)` que buscará libros y admite los siguientes tipos de cadenas de búsqueda:

- "*20*" devolverá todos los libros que contengan 20 en el título, los autores, la editorial o en el Año de publicación ('20', '200', 120 etc)
- "*20* & *peter*" => libros que cumplen *20* y también *peter

Aquí la cadena & es el literal & y el & es una operación booleana que une las dos consultas.

Para ello, tengo lo siguiente desarrallado, pero obtengo el error `Cannot invoke "String.matches(String)" because "this.Title" is null` y no se como repararlo

```
List<Book> FindBooks(String query) {
        List<Book> results = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] queries = query.split("&");
        for (String q : queries) {
            q = q.trim();
            List<Book> temp = new ArrayList<>();

            if (q.startsWith("*") && q.endsWith("*")) {
                String keyword = q.substring(1, q.length() - 1).toLowerCase();

                for (Book book : books) {
                    if (book.contains(keyword)) {
                        temp.add(book);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (Book book : books) {
                    if (book.matches(q)) {
                        temp.add(book);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (results.isEmpty()) {
                results.addAll(temp);
            } else {
                results.retainAll(temp);
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a ser el malo de la película... como decimos en mi país, "está muy flojito de papeles".
Vamos por partes, la clase Book, debe tener un constructor, los getters y los setters, esto deja afuera a los métodos **FindBooks** y **ReadBooks** que deben "vivir" en otra clase.

```
public class Book {

   List <String> Authors;
   String Title;
   String Publisher;
   int PublicationYear;

   public Book( List<String> aut, String tit, String pub, int año ) {
      Authors = aut;
      Title = tit;
      Publisher = pub;
      PublicationYear = año;
   }

   public List<String> getAuthors() {
      return Authors;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
      return Title;
   }

   public String getPublisher() {
      return Publisher;
   }

   public int getPublicationYear() {
      return PublicationYear;
   }   
}
```

Ahora vemos la otra clase, que podríamos llamar **Principal** y el método **ReadBooks**.

```
public class Principal() {
   List<String> Authors;
   private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

   List<Book> ReadBooks( String input ) {
      this.Authors = new ArrayList<>();
      String Title = "";
      String Publisher = "";
      int PublicationYear = 0;
      String[] fieldSeparator = input.split( "\n" );

      for( int i = 1; i < fieldSeparator.length; i++ ) {
         String[] separator = fieldSeparator[ i ].split( ":" );
         String key = separator[ 0 ].trim();
         String value = separator[ 1 ].trim();

         switch( key ) {
            case "Author":
               Authors.add( value );
               break;

            case "Title":
               Title = value;
               break;

            case "Publisher":
               Publisher = value;
               break;

            case "Published":
               PublicationYear = Integer.parseInt( value );
               break;
         }
      }
      Book book = new Book( Authors, Title, Publisher, PublicationYear );
      books.add( book );
      return books;
   }
```

Como podes ver, hice muy pocos cambios, agregué un par de variables, que luego uso para pasar como parámetros al constructor de **Book**.

Y vamos a donde las papas queman... la falla que tenías se debe a que buscabas (por ej.) la palabra "hola" en Book... lo que obviamente no tiene sentido, deberías buscar en books.Title y otros.
Ahora bien, como no estamos dentro de la clase Book, vamos a usar los getters de esta.

```
List<Book> FindBooks( String query ) {
      List<Book> results = new ArrayList<>();

      String[] queries = query.split( "&" );
      for( String q : queries ) {
         q = q.trim();
         List<Book> temp = new ArrayList<>();

         if( q.startsWith( "*" ) && q.endsWith( "*" ) ) {
            String keyword = q.substring( 1, q.length() - 1 ).toLowerCase();

            for( Book book : books ) {
               if( book.getTitle().contains( keyword ) ||
                   book.getPublisher().contains( keyword ) ||
                   String.valueOf( book.getPublicationYear() ).contains( keyword ) ) {
                  temp.add( book );
               }
               for( int i = 0; i < Authors.size(); i++ ) {
                  if( book.getAuthors().get( i ).contains( keyword )) {
                     temp.add( book );
                  }                  
               }
            }
         }
         else {
            for( Book book : books ) {
               if( book.getTitle().matches( q ) ||
                   book.getPublisher().matches( q ) ||
                   String.valueOf( book.getPublicationYear() ).matches( q ) ) {
                  temp.add( book );
               }
               for( int i = 0; i < Authors.size(); i++ ) {
                  if( book.getAuthors().get( i ).matches( q )) {
                     temp.add( book );
                  }                  
               }
            }
         }
         if( results.isEmpty() ) {
            results.addAll( temp );
         }
         else {
            results.retainAll( temp );
         }
      }
      return results;
   }    
}
```

Los cambios también son pocos, solo modifiqué sobre "quiénes" se realiza la busqueda, usando **||** para obtener un valor "true" si cualquiera de las comprobaciones devuelve verdadero, y en el caso particular del autor/es, implemente otro for que recorre las lista de estos.
Espero no haber cometido ningún error, me estoy durmiendo, dicho de otra forma, revisa!!!.